# В чем разница между div и span

Tags: html

Я новичок в программировании и хотелось бы досконально разобраться в чем разница между `div` и `span`.Стоит ли использовать только `div` или только `span` или их нужно как-то комбинировать.
  И кому лучше присваивать название класса, только `div-у` или `span-у`,или опять таки комбинировать.

Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: это разные типы элементов, по умолчанию они имеют разное поведение, но стилями может быть все изменено с точностью до наоборот

Comment: Div - используется как контейнер, а span как обрамление для текста, span - строчный элемент, используется как выделение текста, пример: <p>Some<span>thing</span></p>. Если тег p, блочный, он будет переносить текст на новую строку, а span - строчный, он не переносится, а идёт в линию. Div - нужен для создания контейнеров, в которые необходимо что-то положить, либо же для создания какого-то объекта.

Comment: DIV - блочный эл-т, SPAN - строчный, это вообще основа основ вёрстки, которая к программированию не имеет прямого отношения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути (если не использовать CSS) то разница такая,
если делать блоки **div** то каждый блок будет на новой строке ,а для **span** на этой-же, например

```
<div>
  1
</div>
<div>
  2
</div>
<div>
  3
</div>
<span>
  4
</span>
<span>
  5
</span>
<span>
  6
</span>
```

выдаст

```
1
2
3
4 5 6
```

Если нужно группировать на одной строке то **span**, если на новой то **div**, это свойство можно переопределить через CSS с помощью **display: block** (**div**), и **display: inline** (**span**)